# Problems while working with apache-spark that is on EC2 (Master), from a local machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, localhost, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, master-slave

I am using the Apache Spark 1.3.0 and Hadoop 1.0.4
I have managed to install everything on EC2, and I am running everything from EC2 without any issues. Master and Slaves are running as expected.

What I want to do now is to run this from a local machine, and have the Master (which is on ec2) accessed by issuing:

./spark-shell --master spark://ec2-blahblah.compute.amazonaws.com:7077 --conf key=/blah/blah.pem  --driver-cores 4 --executor-memory 512m

What I am getting (with and without changing the cores and executor memory) is an inability to connect to spark://ec2-blahblah.compute.amazonaws.com

Also, I am getting the famous: WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

What am I doing wrong?

What configurations do I need to set?

How do I secure the connection to "./spark-shell --master spark://ec2-blahblah.compute.amazon...." without using YARN?

EDIT, The errors I get are:

```
    ...
After setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey
...
scala> val csv = sc.textFile("s3n://LOCATION OF A FILE”)
 15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(35538) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278019440
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 34.7 KB, free 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5406) called with curMem=35538, maxMem=278019440
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.3 KB, free 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.188:54529 (size: 5.3 KB, free: 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
15/03/27 15:25:05 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at <console>:21
csv: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = s3n://rtlm-dev/Iris_rtlm.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:21

scala> val cnt = csv.count
15/03/27 15:25:17 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-11-115-141.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/52.11.115.141:9000. Already tried 0 time(s).
15/03/27 15:25:26 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: ec2-52-11-115-141.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/52.11.115.141:9000. Already tried 1 time(s).
—————————————
Second error is (when trying to do the PI example)

15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at <console>:33
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at <console>:33) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(reduce at <console>:33)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:29), which has no missing parents
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1912) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278019440
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1912.0 B, free 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1307) called with curMem=1912, maxMem=278019440
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1307.0 B, free 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.188:54583 (size: 1307.0 B, free: 265.1 MB)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:29)
15/03/27 15:29:04 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
15/03/27 15:29:19 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Comment: The first error looks like you have trouble connecting to S3. But the second one looks like your cluster is not setup correctly. So what does master Web UI show? When you run startup scripts, what do the logs show? Can all your machines see each other with propert hostnames?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a security rule that allows access to the port 7077 from your machine?

Comment: Interesting, where should I add this rule ?  (Hvala puno!)

Comment: Edit: If you are talking about EC2 rules, all TCP is allowed

Comment: What is the exact error you get when starting spark-shell? (Nema na cemu :) )

Comment: Please see the updated question, I have added the messages I see  (I have skipped the loading display INFO part, let me know if you are interested in any particular line from it)

Comment: I am dumbfounded as I am trying to solve this for 2 days... any ideas ? (ps edited the title, thanks!)

Comment: Did you set up Hadoop for S3 access as it says here: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 ?

Comment: No, I have simply ran (from the prebuild with Hadoop) the ./spark-ec2 --key-pair=rtlm-dev2 --identity-file=/blahblah/.pem -t $INSTANCETYPE -r $REGION -s $CLUSTERK launch damirCluster.... then I let BOTO do it all by itself.... I will take a look at the link you gave me, and let you know as soon as I find out.  Have a great weekend!

Comment: Opening 7077 to the world is a huge security risk, since that will allow anyone to submit arbitrary Spark jobs to your cluster.  I strongly recommend against this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly binding to the public EC2 name?

In `spark-env.sh`:

```
export SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS=ec2-blahblah.compute.amazonaws.com
export STANDALONE_SPARK_MASTER_HOST=ec2-blahblah.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Additionally, try setting `SPARK_MASTER_IP` as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will let you know as soon as I get some free time to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error as well, and besides posts above, me myself found that, the security rule for ec2 instances should open all ports ideally, since i checked the documentation and it seems the master/worker communication will randomly choose a port number and binding on that port...

my solution is to use a sub-net and private IP, then open all ports within the subnet. maybe you can have a try.

Also, if you have a cluster with multiple ec2 instance, i.e. with one ec2 instance specialized as master and couple other ec2 instances as workers, then the cluster mode "standalone" may not work, change it to have a try.

Comment: By default the spark ec2 scripts deploy in the standalone mode. I an not sure of what you mean by " ec2 instances as workers, then the cluster mode "standalone" may not work" here. Please explain